# Foreignkey usando User em outra models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Estou desenvolvendo um site de cotação pra fins de estudo da linguagem. Customizei a models User e nela inclui outro atributos, como endereço e cidade por exemplo. O problema, agora, é gravar o ID do usuário logado no campo relacionado, ou seja, a minha tabela de cotação tem um campo `client` que recebe o *`id` do usuário logado*, para que na hora de criar a cotação este `id` seja gravado. Se eu fizer isto pelo Admin dá certo! Se eu adicionar o campo 'client' via `forms.py` pela classe Meta, dá certo! por que eu posso escolher o usuário logado ou outro da lista. Mas o certo é gravar direto o id sem precisar mostrar ou escolher usuário.

O que fiz de errado nos códigos abaixo?

```py
models.py

from django.db import models
from qnow_user.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime,date
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.
class Quotation(models.Model):
    #User owner quotation
    client = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quotation',
        help_text='Cliente dono desta cotação')    

    #Date create of quotation
    date_create = models.DateField('Data Criação',default=date.today,
        help_text='Data em que foi criada esta cotação.')

    date_update = models.DateField('Data Atualização',default=date.today,
        help_text='Data em que foi modificada esta cotação.')

    #House type to quotation
    HOUSETYPECHOICES = (
    ('Apartamento', 'Apartamento'),
    ('Casa', 'Casa'),
    ('Comercial', 'Comercial'),
    ('Escritório', 'Escritório'),
    ('Outros', 'Outros'),
    )
    house_type = models.CharField('Tipo do Imóvel',max_length=20,
                choices=HOUSETYPECHOICES,blank=False,default='Casa',
                help_text='Especifique o seu tipo de imóvel')

    STATUSCHOICES = (
        (0,'Pendente'),   #Client requested quotation
        (1,'Em Análise'), #Company analizing quotation
        (2,'Liberado'),   #Quotation released for provider
        (3,'Orçado'),     #Quotation provider

    )
    status = models.IntegerField('Situação do Pedido',choices=STATUSCHOICES, blank=True,default=0,
        help_text='Difinia a situação atual desta cotação.')

    #House set to quotation                
    house_set = models.CharField('Tipo de Residencial', max_length=100, default='Casa particular',
                help_text='Especifique o nome do seu condomínio ou residencial.')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cotação'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cotações'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.house_set

forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Quotation
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from qnow_user.models import User


User = get_user_model()

class QuotationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quotation
        fields = ('client','date_create', 'date_update', 'house_type',
            'house_set',
        )

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import datetime
from .models import Quotation
from .forms import QuotationForm

@login_required
def quotation_client(request):
    template_name = '../templates/client_quotation.html'
    form = QuotationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #    quotation_client = Quotation.objects.get_or_create(client=request.user)    
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Cotação Feita</h1>")
        else:
            form = QuotationForm()
    else:
        form = QuotationForm()
    print('tetse')
    context = {
                'active_page_client_provider' : 'active',
                'form':form
                }
    return render(request,template_name,context)
#return HttpResponse("<h1>Área do cliente no cliente2</h1>")

admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Quotation

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Quotation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tira o client do form, com isso vc não vai exibir nada do cliente

```
class QuotationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quotation
        fields = ('date_create', 'date_update', 'house_type',
            'house_set',
        )
```

Na hora de salvar, em vez de salvar direto o "form" você pega a instancia de Quotation, adiciona o user logado e salva:

```
@login_required
def quotation_client(request):
    template_name = '../templates/client_quotation.html'
    form = QuotationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if form.is_valid():
            quotation = form.save(commit=False)
            quotation.client = request.user
            quotation.save()
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Cotação Feita</h1>")
        else:
            form = QuotationForm()
    else:
        form = QuotationForm()
    print('tetse')
    context = {
                'active_page_client_provider' : 'active',
                'form':form
                }
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Obrigado Ricardo, eu acabei a minutos atrás descobrindo via outros meios a mesma
coisa que tu me passou. E pelo que vi acertei. Veja como ficou agora.

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Quotation
from .forms import QuotationForm

@login_required
def quotation_client(request):
    template_name = '../templates/client_quotation.html'
    form = QuotationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            Quotation = form.save(commit=False)
            Quotation.client = request.user
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return redirect('qnow_site:site')
            else:
                form = QuotationForm()
        else:
            context = {
                'origin':'client',
                'active_page_client_provider':'active'
            }
            return redirect('qnow_user:login_client')
    else:
        form = QuotationForm()
    context = {
                'active_page_client_provider' : 'active',
                'form':form
                }
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```